# Como usar a API do Google Maps em um Windows Form em c#?

Tags: c#, google-maps-api-3

Estou tendo problemas em como fazer isso. Meu TCC possui uma aba onde aparece uns endereços (Label), onde, ao clicar, quero que o endereço apareça no Maps. Já pensei em usar o WebBrowser, mas não quero que o usuário fique navegando além daquele endereço.

[image: Exemplo]

Quero que essa janela apareça. Mas não não sei o que fazer.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações pois costumamos manter o texto o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [chat]. Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [meta] :)

Answer (score -1):

Você não disse se esses endereços serão estáticos ou não.
Caso seja estático, você pode fazer assim:

1. Busque cada local no site do google maps e ajuste o nível de zoom, tipo de terreno e etc.
2. Ainda no site do google maps, clique no botão de menu(aqueles três risquinhos no cando superior direito) e depois clique em *Compartilhar ou incorporar mapa*.
3. Clique em incorporar mapa, faça os ajustes necessários e copie o código gerado.Faça isso para cada endereço.
4. Adicione a seu form uma WebView e cada vez que clicar em um endereço você chama a função abaixo passando como parâmetro o código gerado por cada endereço no google.

Desse modo o WebView irá exibir somente a porção do mapa escolhida por você
Código:

```
public void updateWebView(string codigoIncorporado)
{
    webBrowser1.Refresh();
    var str = "<html><head></head><body>" + codigoIncorporado + "</body></html>";
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = str;
}
```